# Is it possible to convert ConfigParser options to a type during parsing?

Tags: python-3.x, jinja2

When using a [`ConfigParser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser-objects) instance it is possible to *explicitly* convert an option to a type by way of its `getint`, `getfloat`, and `getboolean` methods. And the list of supported types can be extended by passing the appropriate value for the `converters` named argument of the constructor.

So explicit works nicely.

Now consider the following script, containing an `.ini` file and a Jinja2 template inline:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
assert sys.version_info[:2] >= (3, 5), "Need at least Python 3.5"
from configparser import ConfigParser
from io import StringIO
from jinja2 import Template

INI_FILE = """\
[section]
option1 = yes
option2 = no"""

TPL_FILE = """\
From loop:
{% for opt in cfg.options("section") -%}
{{ opt }} = {{ cfg.get("section", opt) }}
{% endfor -%}
Directly:
option1 = {{ cfg.section.option1 }}
option2 = {{ cfg.section.option2 }}
real true = {{ realt }}
real false = {{ realf }}
"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cfg = ConfigParser()
    cfgfile = StringIO(INI_FILE)
    cfg.read_file(cfgfile)
    # cfg["section"]["option3"] = True <- must be string
    # cfg["section"]["option4"] = False <- ditto
    tpl = Template(TPL_FILE)
    print(tpl.render(cfg=cfg, realt=True, realf=False))
```

The output is:

```
From loop:
option1 = yes
option2 = no
Directly:
option1 = yes
option2 = no
real true = True
real false = False
```

Now how can I achieve that whenever `option1` and `option2` are accessed, they are treated as boolean just like the real boolean values I am passing under the names `realt` and `realf` respectively?

`ConfigParser` appears to treat everything as a string.

I see two methods to achieve what I want.

1. One would be to write a Jinja2 filter that accepts the various string forms allowed to be used (and apparently recognized by [`getboolean()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.getboolean))
2. Another method could be to derive `ConfigParser` and implement this behavior somehow.

However, seeing that method 1 would duplicate code (and my code would not automatically change with the code in `ConfigParser`, so implementations can conceivably diverge); and that method 2 could as well end up duplicating information in several places, I am wondering if the batteries-included approach of Python has something of the sort included that I am missing.

How can I make `get`, `set` and `__setitem__`, `__getitem__` aware of the standard types (`int`, `float`, `boolean`) supported by `ConfigParser`? What other methods am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

For now I am settling for a custom Jinja2 filter that takes a string value as input and uses `ConfigParser` to parse it as boolean. I find it ugly, though and would still like to see a better answer from someone else.

```
def my_filter(optvalue):
    assert isinstance(optvalue, str), "We expect only string values as input from ConfigParser"
    from configparser import ConfigParser, DEFAULTSECT
    cfg = ConfigParser()
    cfg.read_string("[%s]\n%s = %s\n" % (DEFAULTSECT, DEFAULTSECT, optvalue))
    return cfg.getboolean(DEFAULTSECT, DEFAULTSECT)
```

This way I can now do (assuming the filter was registered as `asbool`):

```
option2 = {{ cfg.section.option2|asbool }}
```

... or in conditions:

```
{% if cfg.section.option2|asbool %}
something ...
{% endif %}
```